# Registration screen Android

Tags: android

I'm am doing a registration screen as a first page in my application, in the MainActivity.java I put :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private EditText  username=null;
       private EditText  password=null;
       private TextView attempts;
       private Button login;
       int counter = 3;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
          attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
          login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       }

       public void login(View view){
          if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
          password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }    
       else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   
          counter--;
          attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
          if(counter==0){
             login.setEnabled(false);
          }

       }}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

In the xml page I put :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="attempts" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The error I get is in the java code when writing :

```
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

**editText1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.
Same to editText2 , textView3 and button1**

Please any help ?

Comment: import the correct R file

Comment: I did the imports, How can I import the correct R file ?

Comment: I'm not getting any error in your code. But you did not call on onClick () method for your button1. Try to clean and build the project.

Comment: @Angel : save the xml file (layout) , and try clean and build the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have own solution.I hope it helps to you .

In `Project->Clean` I select "Clean projects selected below", select my project(s) and check "Start a build immediately" with "Build only selected projects".

Then go to `Window->Preferences->General->Keys`, search "Build clean" and enter my own binding for this command. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Then, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and Enter I have clean and build.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an ID like `@+id/editText1` in your layout file, your IDE should usually take care of generating the values in R.java for you. If that code generation step hasn't happened or has failed for some reason, then R.id.editText1 won't be available and you'll get the error you described.

Which IDE are you using? Can you clean and rebuild the project?

Did you have a look at R.java to see if your field is in there? For each ID in any of the layout files you should see a constant generated in there, like this:

```
public final class R {
  (...)

  public static final class id {
    public static final int editText1 = ...;
  }

  (...)
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? Android Studio? These things either happen automatically (which arguably they don't for you) or when you hit "Build project" (or something similar). If it doesn't work, try a "Clean project" before that. Usually that shouldn't be necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

First , `save` the file (layout) , and try `clean and build the project`

Then :
change the declaration to :

```
  private EditText  username;
       private EditText  password;
```

Also change the name of l`ogin method` because you have a `button` named `login` to `loginFunction` for example,

```
 public void loginFunction(View view)
```

ans associate this method to button `login` in `setOnclickListener` :

```
login.setOnclickListener(loginFunction)
```

Comment: The error disappeared but when running it gives me this problem:

Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex Conversion to Dalvik format ..

what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

First **Clean and rebuild** your project. If no luck then try the following.

Sometimes this is happening in xml layout files when missing a closing tag or something like that. Just double check your xml to make sure that you didn't forget something. Also
check `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is in the top of the layout file.